# Send post to server and get result via android

Tags: android, json, webapi

If I want to read json from web api , first I need to POST some json into server , so my code will be :

```
   private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      InputStream inputStream = null;
      StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
      @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.54.180.18:8090/TV/api/GetUserInfo");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", default_token);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("accountNo", "cb2c2041d9763d84d7d655e81178f444");
            jsonObject.put("stationNo", "NURS4");
            jsonObject.put("bedNo", "329-1");

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            //get response
            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            for (int n; (n = inputStream.read(b)) != -1;) {
                out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
            }
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return out.toString();
```

now I want to see repose result(JSON) , what do I do ? please help me , thanks.

Comment: Read the reply from conn.getInputStream().

Comment: os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));` Remove that line. The next line will send the json. And you dont need to send it twice.

Comment: Retrofit is the industry standard for making requests on Android. Have a look at this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask instead of Thread for send data to server.It offers methods

1. preExecute()
2. doInBackround()
3. onProgressUpdate
4. postExecute()

override these methods. write your code for server connection inside doInBackground() method.
Handle the result on postExecute()

create a class--
class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
    //String result = write code to connect to server & send data in background thread
    return result;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(a);

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
```

}

call it in activity
new MyTask().execute();

follow the links

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask